# Lost in the outputs of a mixed linear model

Tags: r, mixed-model, interpretation

I am facing an issue trying to build a linear mixed model.

Here is the question I'd like to answer to: in a `df`, I have put some wings measurements for 18,538 birds and the year it was measured for each bird, from 1995 to 2018.

I would like to test if on the time period considered, the mean size of the birds' wings is significantly increasing or not. I have taken into account a random effect for the species, and built this model:

```
mixed_model = lmer(formula = "wing_tot ~ year + (1 | species)",
                     REML = FALSE,
                     data = df)
```

Here are the results:

```
> summary(mixed_model)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use
  Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: "wing_tot ~ year + (1 | espece)"
   Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
121900.9 121932.2 -60946.4 121892.9    18534 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.1463  -0.4146   0.0157   0.4556  16.7972 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 species (Intercept) 366.4    19.141  
 Residual              39.1     6.253  
Number of obs: 18538, groups:  species, 229

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.380e+02  1.876e+01  1.846e+04   7.358 1.95e-13 ***
year        -3.209e-02  9.315e-03  1.832e+04  -3.444 0.000574 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
year -0.998
```

I am lost with the analysis of the results :( Does this code seem logical to you or did I make some (silly) mistakes? Would you analyze the output value in “year” (`-3.209e-02`) as that the mean size of the wings are significantly **decreasing** of `3.209e-02` cm on the whole period?

Then, I also modified the `df` like this:

```
df$year <- as.factor(df$year)
```

and obtained these results (all the years now appear distinctly):

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use
  Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: "wing_tot ~ year + (1 | species)"
   Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
128046.4 128251.3 -63997.2 127994.4    19568 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.6373  -0.4317   0.0098   0.4599  17.0284 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 species (Intercept) 364.39   19.089  
 Residual              37.55    6.128  
Number of obs: 19594, groups:  species, 231

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  7.401e+01  1.521e+00  4.879e+02  48.666  < 2e-16
year1996     8.722e-01  1.030e+00  1.937e+04   0.847 0.397031
year1997    -1.372e+00  9.711e-01  1.937e+04  -1.413 0.157652
year1998    -2.285e-01  9.994e-01  1.938e+04  -0.229 0.819144
year1999     1.195e+00  9.185e-01  1.938e+04   1.301 0.193282
year2000     5.503e-01  9.576e-01  1.937e+04   0.575 0.565566
year2000     5.503e-01  9.576e-01  1.937e+04   0.575 0.565566
year2001    -7.143e-01  8.875e-01  1.938e+04  -0.805 0.420923
year2002    -1.109e+00  8.841e-01  1.938e+04  -1.255 0.209559
year2003    -2.776e+00  9.033e-01  1.938e+04  -3.073 0.002121
year2004     1.637e-01  8.754e-01  1.938e+04   0.187 0.851654
year2005    -3.377e+00  8.790e-01  1.938e+04  -3.842 0.000123
year2006    -9.154e-01  8.724e-01  1.938e+04  -1.049 0.294051
year2007     1.068e+00  8.895e-01  1.938e+04   1.201 0.229848
year2008     1.401e-01  8.843e-01  1.938e+04   0.158 0.874160
year2009    -2.911e-01  8.763e-01  1.938e+04  -0.332 0.739728
year2010    -1.972e-01  8.662e-01  1.938e+04  -0.228 0.819909
year2011    -2.614e-01  8.770e-01  1.938e+04  -0.298 0.765689
year2012    -3.106e-02  8.678e-01  1.938e+04  -0.036 0.971451
year2013    -3.328e-01  8.734e-01  1.938e+04  -0.381 0.703161
year2014    -2.186e-01  8.796e-01  1.938e+04  -0.249 0.803733
year2015    -3.749e-01  8.738e-01  1.938e+04  -0.429 0.667864
year2016    -1.388e+00  8.750e-01  1.938e+04  -1.587 0.112626
year2017    -2.246e+00  8.707e-01  1.938e+04  -2.580 0.009899
year2018     2.230e+00  1.403e+00  1.937e+04   1.589 0.112041

(Intercept) ***
year1996       
year1997       
year1998       
year1999       
year2000       
year2001       
year2002       
year2003    ** 
year2004       
year2005    ***
year2006       
year2007       
year2008       
year2009       
year2010       
year2011       
year2012       
year2013       
year2014       
year2015       
year2016       
year2017    ** 
year2018       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 24 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it
```

To sum up, I don't know if the codes are well-written, which one is correct, and why, and what would be the best way to analyze the results according the question...

Sorry for the long question, thank you in advance for the help! :)

Comment: The coefficient for year in the first one is the change per year so it is going down by 0.3 mm per year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current mixed model `wing_tot ~ year + (1 | species)` includes a random intercept for species. This means that you are modelling the average wing size of each species as being drawn from a Gaussian distribution. According to your model fit the estimated mean of this distribution is 1.380e+02 and the variance is 366.4. To know whether this assumption is justified you have to consider how many different species you collected data from (enough to estimate a Gaussian distribution from?), and whether a Gaussian distribution is indeed how wing size is distributed (I don't know much about birds but perhaps the wing size is not symmetrically distributed around some mean as there is a lower limit how small the wings can be but no upper limit?). However, even if both of these conditions do not hold it is probably still better to include the random intercept rather than leaving it out.

Another potential issue is that your model currently is assuming that wing size does not change differently for each species by year. Perhaps this is something you also want to control for in your model? If you do then you can include a random slope of year by writing `wing_tot ~ year + (1 + year | species)`.

> Would you analize the output value in "year" (-3.209e-02) as that the
> mean size of the wings are significantly decreasing of 3.209e-02cm on
> the whole period?

yes, that's what the output suggests. However, in order to determine whether this is significant you might want to also fit a model without the fixed effect of year, i.e. `wing_tot ~ 1 + (1 | species)`, and then do a model comparison between your fit and that fit, i.e. `anova(fit1,fit2)`.

I think your final analysis where you are testing each year separately is not particularly useful for answering your question of interest. (There also seems to be a bug somewhere in your code as `year2000` is included twice). However, it can be used to answer a related question. Perhaps you're interested in whether the effect of year on wing size is linear (which you are currently testing) or changes in some other non-linear way. One way of testing this is to include other terms in your model, such as the log of year or the square of year, and testing whether they are significant. However, rather than including arbitrary terms it might be better to develop a visual intuition first. One way of doing this is to plot the average wing size for each year, which is essentially what your regression is computing.

[image]

As you can see from the plot there seems to be some structure in your data: the points up until ~2006 appear to have a higher variance than points from ~2007-2017. 2018 appears to be an outlier. Perhaps it's worth thinking about whether there is anything different about how this data was collected? Another issue could be whether there is data for every species for each year or do you only have data for some species for some years? It might also be worth making similar plots to the one I made for each of your species.